# Can't destroy transform of "". if you want to destroy the game object, please call destroy on the game object instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

I got a quick question.

I have a List of objects that is regularly accessed by another script. What I want to do is clear the list and destroy all objects in it. Here is the code I am using to do this:

FoodTargets is the name of my List...

```
    destroycounter = FoodTargets.Count;

    for (destroycounter = 0; destroycounter < FoodTargets.Count; destroycounter++)
    {
        Destroy(FoodTargets[destroycounter]);
        FoodTargets.RemoveAt(destroycounter);
    }
```

This returns the error:

> Can't destroy transform of "". if you want to destroy the game object,
>   please call destroy on the game object instead...

I've been at this for hours, I just want to know what line of code I can use to destroy the instantiated prefab inside the list... OR if possible, what code do I use to destroy all instantiated prefabs in a List. Thanks in advance, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you try: `Destroy(FoodTargets)`; without the for loop?

Comment: I've tried it. But it is returning the error: Assets/Scrpits/HerbivoreScript.cs(92,17): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.Transform>' expression to type `UnityEngine.Object'

Comment: @Max No, that won't work in Unity3D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that each transform points to its GameObject. You have to do this because [**Destroy()**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) takes a [**GameObject**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) as a parameter.

```
Destroy(transformReference.gameObject);
```

---

**In your code it would look like this**:

```
Destroy(FoodTargets[destroycounter].gameObject);
```

---

You can read more about the properties inside the [**Transform here**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html).